# ORDER BY command using a prepared statement parameter pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm new to Node, APIs and SQL and I hit a wall. I'm using `pg-promise` prepared statements and I'm trying to use a `sorted` parameter with the `ORDERED BY` command to do the usual sorting of the results but it doesn't work as the always come in ordered the same.
If I us the parameter's name directly it does work instead, can you see what am I doing wrong with my query?
As usual many thanks for your time and help.
This is my method:

```
if (city, region, country, category, minPrice, maxPrice, orderedBy, sorted) {
    if (sorted == 'asc') {
      await db.any({
        name: 'get-city-category-price-range-ordered-by-asc-products',
        // text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3 AND category = $4 AND price >= $5 AND price <= $6 ORDER BY price ASC', // working
        text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3 AND category = $4 AND price >= $5 AND price <= $6 ORDER BY $7 ASC', // not working
        values: [city, region, country, category, minPrice, maxPrice, orderedBy]
      })
        .then(result => {
          console.log('get-city-category-price-range-ordered-by-asc-products:', result);
          if (result.length > 0) {
            res.status(200).send({
              data: result
            });
          }
          else {
            res.status(404).send({
              error: 'No product found.'
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('get-city-category-price-range-ordered-by-asc-products error:', error);
        });

    } else if (sorted == 'desc') {
      await db.any({
        name: 'get-city-category-price-range-ordered-by-desc-products',
        // text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3 AND category = $4 AND price >= $5 AND price <= $6 ORDER BY price DESC', // working
        text: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3 AND category = $4 AND price >= $5 AND price <= $6 ORDER BY $7 DESC', // not working
        values: [city, region, country, category, minPrice, maxPrice, orderedBy]
      })
        .then(result => {
          console.log('get-city-category-price-range-ordered-by-desc-products:', result);
          if (result.length > 0) {
            res.status(200).send({
              data: result
            });
          }
          else {
            res.status(404).send({
              error: 'No product found.'
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('get-city-category-price-range-ordered-by-desc-products error:', error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you opt for [PreparedStatement](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html), your query formatting is done on the server side. So if you decided to use [PreparedStatement](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) for exactly that purpose, to get values formatted by the server, then you will have to do without the rich query formatting that [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) supports internally for regular queries, and limiting yourself to what PostgreSQL server can do in that regard. And unlike [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), PostgreSQL server doesn't allow dynamic SQL names or identifiers anywhere.

However, if your chose [PreparedStatement](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) because you think in your case it will execute faster, then you can still benefit from rich query formatting supported by `pg-promise`, by formatting the query separately, and then executing [PreparedStatement](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) with pre-formatted query, i.e. without any parameters:

```js
const text = pgp.as.format(`SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $/city/
                            AND region = $/region/ AND country = $/country/
                            AND category = $/category/
                            AND price BETWEEN $/minPrice/ AND $/maxPrice/
                            ORDER BY $/orderedBy:name/ $/sorted:value/`, {
                              city, region, country, category,
                              minPrice, maxPrice, orderedBy, sorted
                            });

const name = 'get-price-range-ordered-by-products-' + sorted; // unique query name

await db.any({name, text});
```

As you can see, the sorting order can also be set dynamically, no need duplicating your code. And we append `sorted` to the query's `name`, because it generates a different execution path, which requires a unique query name.

P.S. I'm the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I'm actually choosing it for SQLI protection, not for execution speed, ( you asked because PreparedStatements are slow? I saw the Performance Boost article ) . Indeed I'm going through some code duplicate as I'm just starting out and wrapping my head around sql concepts and pg-promise,  so at times I might choose the more verbose approach and refactor the code as I progress as in this case for the `format` method. Thanks again for the library.

Comment: I do get an error `Prepared statements must be unique` when swapping `ASC` for `DESC` in the sorted property and run the request again.

Comment: That's because a different sorting order creates internally a different query path on the server, but you give it the same name, hence the error thrown by the server. See I updated my answer, by appending `sorted` to the end of the query's `name`.

Comment: indeed, it happened to me wit old code and I tried to inserting it into the string like `get-city-category-price-range-ordered-by-${orderedBy}-${sorted}-products` or  but didn't work as the replacement failed for know knowing the type .. appending indeed works as ended up doing.

Comment: I was checking the format method and is stated in the docs that for `:name` and `:value` `{}` could be used as well , but I tried as it's  more familiar to me than `/ /`, but throws me an error expecting `}`before `:`.. any other suggested symbol works..

Comment: You can't use `{}` for queries inside ES6 template strings, [as explained in docs](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters).

Comment: sure, I was reading here http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot use query parameters for things like column and table names, only for values. So this will never work, you'll need to build the SQL text by hand by adding the proper "order by" statement. All the warnings about SQL injection then apply, so please check that your orderBy field is valid (for example, only contains letters, no whitespace or other characters).

Comment: Thank you for answering. As I only have 3 order by cases I could then just implement a switch to check the 'orderedBy` query parameter and form the correct  SQL text, would this be safe enough against SQLI?

Comment: Yes, it would be safer to only build your SQL from constant strings instead of strings coming from the user.

Comment: sure, the orderedBy parameter( as other parameters) is selected from a drop down menu. Only product creation does have user input, but `pg-promise`and prepared statements do take care of escaping for SQLi right?